# Vue slick carousel slider asNavFor problem

Tags: vue.js

This one is for Big image slider

```
  <VueSlickCarousel v-if="changeableImages && changeableImages.length > 0"
      ref="c1"
     :focusOnSelect="true">
     <div v-for="(image, imageIndex) in changeableImages" :key="'c1_image_' + imageIndex">
          <img :src="image.imagePath">
     </div>
 </VueSlickCarousel>
```

This one is for small image slider.

```
 <VueSlickCarousel v-if="changeableImages && changeableImages.length > 0"
      ref="c2"
      :asNavFor="$refs.c1"
      :slidesToShow="4"
     :focusOnSelect="true">
     <div v-for="(image, imageIndex) in changeableImages" :key="'c1_image_' + imageIndex">
          <img :src="image.imagePath">
     </div>
 </VueSlickCarousel>
```

on view methods:

```
imageFilterChange() {
    let newChangeableImages = [];
    changeableImages.$set(this, 'changeableImages', newChangeableImages);
}
```

**My problem:** when I change the `changeableImages` from vue methods, sometimes `asNavFor` doesn't work properly. I mean, small slider don't navigate proper image from big slider.

**package used:** `"vue-slick-carousel": "^1.0.6"` on `"vue": "^2.6.11"`

Comment: Could you provide a link to a sandbox where you replicate this? Also, I see you assign a value to a variable `newChangeableImages` but I don't see that used anywhere else

Comment: @LupuȘtefanAlex, variable, `newChangeableImages ` was a mistake. I update it. And then, tried to create that thing on sandbox. But couldn't able to make it. after that, I found a bandaid solution. that helps me. here is the issue link.
https://github.com/gs-shop/vue-slick-carousel/issues/84